# Simplification & Differentiation of $\frac{2x}{x^{1/3}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

Above is the image I had taken a snap shot of.
I was working on the problem # 24.
I got to rewrite the function as: 
$y = 2x(x^{-1/3})$
I differentiated it and got the $y'$ as:
$y' = (2x)(-1/3)(x^{-4/3}) + (2)(x^{-1/3})$
Then I got to the answer as being simplified as:
$y' = \frac{-2}{3(x^3)} + \frac{2}{x^3}$

I am not clearly sure if I have fully simplified it down to the simplest form.
Could anyone verify my answer being right or wrong?

Comment: You need to see that you can simplify the original function: $\frac{2x}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}} = 2x^{1 - \frac{1}{3}} = 2x^{\frac{2}{3}}$...and the final result should be $\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}$

Answer (score 3):

No need for the product rule on this.

$y={2x\over x^{1/3}}=2x*x^{-1/3}=2x^{2/3}$
Then
$y^\prime ={4 \over 3x^{1/3}} $

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[kx^n]=k\frac{d}{dx}[x^n]=knx^{n-1} $$
And
$$ f(x)=\frac{2x}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}}=2x^{\frac{2}{3}} $$
Then
$$ \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]=2\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{2}{3}-1}=\frac{4}{3}x^{\frac{2-3}{3}}=\frac{4}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{4}{3\sqrt[3]{x}} $$